# Обособление "для некоторых людей"

Tags: пунктуация

Нужна помощь с вводными конструкциями. Подскажите пожалуйста, какой вариант будет верным:

*Для некоторых людей,* идея того, что «Магия» имеет практический характер, является неожиданностью. 
*Для некоторых людей* идея того, что «Магия» имеет практический характер, является неожиданностью.

"Для некоторых людей" - это вводные слова? С одной стороны, можно сказать, что данная конструкция имеет смысл "источник сообщения", но с другой, я не нашла примеров предложений, где она могла бы быть обособлена.

Comment: Анна, у меня вопрос не по теме. "Магия" в Вашем предложении — это название какого-то предмета?

Comment: Я делаю перевод текста. По мнению автора, "Магия" является чем-то высоким, жизненно-важным, и потому в предложении слово написано с большой буквы.

Comment: А кавычки тогда зачем?

Comment: Были в оригинальном тексте.

Answer (score 2):

Это не вводная конструкция, а обычный член предложения - косвенное *дополнение* с предлогом и определением, поэтому запятая *не нужна*. Для наглядности сказанного предложение можно упростить так:

> [эта] Идея является неожиданностью [для кого?] для некоторых людей.